# Query preview for three user, class, tables, article laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a logger user I want to show the articles, categories, for this user only.

Database schema:

```
Users:    category:    article:
  id      id           id
  name    name         title
          users_id     categories_id
```

---

**User Model**

```php
class User extends Model

public function Category
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'users_id');
}
```

**category model** (works)

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function article
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class );
    }

    public function users
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'users_id');
    }
```

**article model** (works)

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'categories_id');
    }
```

**Controller category**

```php
 class CategoryController extends Controller
 {
     public function index()
     {
         $categories = Category::all();
         return view('category. view', compact('categories'));
     }

 class Article Controller extends Controller
 {
     public function index()
     {
         $articles = Article::all();
         return view(' article . index', compact('articles'));}
```

Comment: There are a few syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use the following code:

```
public function getArticles(){
      $user = auth()->user();
      $articles = $user->articles;
      return view('articlesView',array('articles' => $articles));
}
    public function getCategories(){
      $user = auth()->user();
      $articles = $user->categories;
      return view('categoryView',array('articles' => $articles));
}
```

In order for these functions to work you need to add these methods to your User model:

```
public function categories(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Category');  
}
public function articles(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Articles');
}
```